# Prove (or disprove) an inequality involving three vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: calculus, geometry, inequality, vectors

> Prove (or disprove) that for any vectors $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}^n, n\ge 2,  \lVert\vec{a}\rVert +  \lVert\vec{b}\rVert + \lVert\vec{c}\rVert +  \lVert\vec{a} + \vec{b} + \vec{c}\rVert\ge \lVert\vec{a} + \vec{b}\rVert + \lVert\vec{a} + \vec{c}\rVert  + \lVert\vec{b} + \vec{c}\rVert  $.

It could be useful to start with $n=2$  and try to generalize.

Maybe it might also be useful to write out all the vectors on both sides as components and use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality or some other useful inequalities (e.g. AM-GM, the rearrangement inequality, etc.)? It might be useful to square both sides beforehand. But this seems very complicated.

The following claim seems to be false: for any vectors $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}^n, |a| + |b| \ge |a - c| + |c - b|$, where $|\cdot |$ denotes the Euclidean norm. For instance, a counterexample would be $a = 91,9,12), b = (-1, 10, -1), c = (2,-1,2)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Perhaps it might also be useful to define $\vec{d} = -\vec{a}-\vec{b}-\vec{c}$ and notice that the inequality is equivalent to proving that $\lVert\vec{a}\rVert +  \lVert\vec{b}\rVert + \lVert\vec{c}\rVert +  \lVert\vec{d}\rVert \ge \lVert\vec{a} + \vec{d}\rVert + \lVert\vec{d} + \vec{c}\rVert  + \lVert\vec{b} + \vec{d}\rVert$

Comment: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/Hlawka.shtml